# Laravel 10 - Passport - Personal Access Client

Tags: laravel, postman

Can someone help me on this. I'm using personal access client to access an APIs in my project. I'm using 'Postman' to test the API but get "Unauthenticated." message i.e 401 errors. I have supply the right token in headers for Authorization i.e. Bearer bytoken.

This is my route :

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->prefix('others')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/info1', [myController::class , 'getInfo1']);
});
```

my url is localhost:8000/api/others/info1 but got 'Unauthenticated' message as a response

What am i missing?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Show us how did you call it in POSTMAN. Should be `Authorization: Bearer {your-token}`

Comment: Make sure route, Auth Middleware and all functions are reachable. You can test by adding `dd` to all places and uncommenting one by one

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does the errors is due to  'api' => [ 
             'driver' => 'passport', 
             'provider' => 'users', 
         ], in auth.php , since personal access client not related to users ?